# How do I switch JavaScript libraries in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I didn't skip prototype when I began my new project and I want to move to JQuery. What is the best way to switch libraries?

Comment: Can you clarify - is your question about setting up jQuery, or is it about converting existing prototype.js code to jQuery?

Comment: I just want to get rid of any reference to Prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the prototype/scriptaculous and rails.js libraries. Then copy jquery and the [ujs adapter for jquery](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to you javascripts directory and include them in your layout.

I recommend checking out the [rails3-generators](http://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators) plugin. It provides generators for common tasks like this. In the jquery case you would just run the `rails g jquery:install` generator and the files would be copied for you and the JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES set in an initializer so that `javascript_include_tag :defaults` still works.

Comment: this is also covered in Railscasts #205 at 10:55

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Rails 3.0 RC:**

I've also been using the JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES reset technique in an initializer for the betas, but have discovered that this is has been removed in Rails 3 RC, which will break your app.

You will typically see either an "undefined method `reset_javascript_include_default'" error or "constant ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES not defined (NameError)"

**The fix / what's changed**

The rails maintainers have refactored the javascript asset tag helpers and moved the default scripts setup within the railtie. So  you simply need to use the following in application.rb:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions = { :defaults => ['jquery', 'rails', 'etc'] }
```

Apologies for my long rambling intro, before the meat - I put it there to help people Googling this issue.